# Accessibility reader automatically starts at main landmark and continues reading from there without reading the rest of the text

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I have a design that is divided into a few steps. The first step is only clickable while the rest are disabled until the first is completed. The problem is the accessibility reader is not reading the first steps text: it is reading the first step button and then continuing on with the rest of the rest of the steps.

```
<div>
  
  <div id='step1' >
    <div>header</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <button>buttonText</button>
  </div> 

  <!-- reader starts at this step1 button and then reads rest of steps but does not read the first header and content text -->

  <div id='step2'>
    <div>headerText2</div>
    <div>content2</div>
    <button disabled></button>
  </div>

  <div id='step3'>
    <div>headerText3</div>
    <div>content3</div>
    <button disabled></button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Hoping for an easy solution with aria labels and/or roles